# How do i stop my WebView in my react-native expo app from rendering every time i open drawer or the screen orientation changes?

Tags: react-native, mobile, webview, rendering, navigation-drawer

I want my WebViews to stay as they are and not re-render unless a specific condition is met i.e i navigate to this page again. Otherwise they should not re-render.

## **The code:**

```js
const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;

class GraphComponent extends Component {
  
    render() {
        console.log('rendering WebView...');
      return (
        <WebView
          source={{ uri: URI' }}
          style={{ flex: 1 , backgroundColor: '1b1b1f',
          bottom: 0,
          width: '100%',
          height: SCREEN_HEIGHT*0.6}}
        />
      );
    }
  }
  export default GraphComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

I called my screens functions inside my drawer Screen which caused them to re-render everytime the drawer opened. I took them outside and fixed the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).